# How do I choose which drivers are installed for a device with other VID and PID?

Tags: windows, usb, pid, drivers

I have a USB controller (STMicroelectronics) which comes with a default VID and PID. When plugged in Windows will install the appropriate drivers automatically. What I want to do is define my own VID & PID (would be officially registered) and still use the same driver. I want to have my own VID & PID since I want to make sure that my program does not try to talk to any device which happens to be using the same USB controller. I've gotten this to work fine on all but Windows 8, because of the stricter driver signature requirements. Is there any way to make this work without modifying/signing the drivers, or should I look into another way of uniquely identify the device as my own? The end user of the device should not be required to do anything out of the ordinary to make the drivers install (especially on Win8).

Comment: You'll have to modify the driver, usually very minor surgery.  Be sure you got the source for it, should not be a problem when you obtained it from the chip manufacturer.  Getting the certificate for it is the cost of business these days and can't be avoided.

Comment: In principle, if for some reason you can't modify the driver as Hans suggests, I think you could write a minimal driver of your own which passes the actual work to the original driver; for example, you could tell Windows that your VID&PID represent a bus device, and present the default VID&PID as a device on that bus.  You would still have to get your driver signed, of course.